# How can I delete last all transaction that made by PHP api?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have Receipt API that generate Receipt. While generating receipt several SQL operation is being done. Now if I generate receipt by mistake how can Undo all last operation.

What I need to do is I want all data as it is before this API call. I have some Idea about `Rollback` but I don't know how can I use this in this. If you help please do so.

My receipt look like this.

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

extract($_REQUEST);
$data = array();
$resArr = array();

$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$cheque_date = $_POST['cheque_date'];
$cheque_no = $_POST['cheque_no'];
$paid_amount = $_POST['paid_amount'];



$query = customSelectQuery(
    "SELECT c.emi_amount as customer_emi_amount, ltc.no_of_month as ltc_no_of_month, 
    ltc.emi_date as ltc_emi_date, ltc.loan_amount as ltc_loan_amount
    from loan_to_customer ltc
    LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = ltc.customer_id
    WHERE ltc.customer_id = $customer_id");

//  print_r($query);

if (isset($query)) {
    $ltc_data = array();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $ltc_data = array(
            'ltc_emi_date' => explode(',', $row['ltc_emi_date']),
            'ltc_no_of_month' => $row['ltc_no_of_month'],
            'ltc_loan_amount' => $row['ltc_loan_amount'],
            'customer_emi_amount' => $row['customer_emi_amount']
        );
    }
}

$ltc_loan_amount = $ltc_data['ltc_loan_amount'];

$remaining_loan_amount = $ltc_loan_amount - $paid_amount;

$receipt_number = 'CMF/EMI/RECEIPT/126';
$receipt_data = array(

    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'payment_type' => $payment_type,
    'cheque_date' => $cheque_date,
    'cheque_no' => $cheque_no,
    'paid_amount' => $paid_amount,
    'remain_amount' => $remaining_loan_amount,
    'receipt_no' => $receipt_number

);

$insert_in_reciept = insert("receipt", $receipt_data);


$removed_emi_date = array_shift($ltc_data['ltc_emi_date']);


$number_of_month_remaining = count($ltc_data['ltc_emi_date']);

$string_number_of_month_remaining = implode(',', $ltc_data['ltc_emi_date']);


$loan_to_customer_data = array(

    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'loan_amount' => $remaining_loan_amount,
    'no_of_month' => $number_of_month_remaining,
    'emi_date' => $string_number_of_month_remaining


);

$update_ltc = update("loan_to_customer", $loan_to_customer_data, 'customer_id = ' . $customer_id);

$query1 = customSelectQuery("select r.*, ltc.emi_date as ltc_emi_date, ltc.*, c.first_name,
c.middle_name, c.last_name, c.gender, c.cust_address, c.cust_city,
c.cust_dist, c.cust_state, c.cust_pincode FROM receipt r 
LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id
LEFT JOIN loan_to_customer ltc ON r.customer_id = ltc.customer_id
WHERE r.customer_id = $customer_id");

if (isset($query1)) {
    $d = array();
    foreach ($query1 as $row) {
        $d = array(
            'first_name' => $row['first_name'],
            'middle_name' => $row['middle_name'],
            'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
            'gender' => $row['gender'],
            'cust_address' => $row['cust_address'],
            'cust_city' => $row['cust_city'],
            'cust_state' => $row['cust_state'],
            'cust_pincode' => $row['cust_pincode'],
            'ltc_emi_date' => explode(',', $row['ltc_emi_date']),
            'payment_type' => $row['payment_type'],
            'cheque_date' => $row['cheque_date'],
            'cheque_no' => $row['cheque_no'],
            'paid_amount' => $row['paid_amount'],
            'remain_amount' => $row['remain_amount'],
            'penalty_amount' => $row['penalty_amount'],
            'receipt_no' => $row['receipt_no'],
            'emi_date' => $row['emi_date'],
            'pending_penalty' => $row['pending_penalty'],
            'paid_penalty' => $row['paid_penalty'],
            'user' => $row['user'],
            'user_branch' => $row['user_branch'],
            'verify' => $row['verify'],
        );
    }
}


$resArr = array("success" => 1, "data" => $d, "message" => "");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo str_replace("\/", "/", json_encode($resArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

?>
```

Comment: You can use Mysql transactions here you go https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: How can I know that @AakashTushar

Comment: check your `connection.php` file. I mean is it `MySqli` or `PDO`?

Comment: I use `MySqli` @AakashTushar

Comment: Are you using `procedural` or `object oriented` pattern? see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: I am  using `procedura`l pattern  @AakashTushar

Comment: Do not use `extract($_REQUEST)`. It is extremely unsafe!

Comment: Yes !! what should I use ?? and How to build token based API so only few user can use it with specified token ?? @Dharman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Of course**, it is not possible to use transactions for a scenario like this.

And there is no reliable way to undo the previous operation with a database structure like this either.

To make it possible you must **normalize** your database. In other words any addition must be done by means of INSERT queries only but not a single UPDATE should to be used.

Given that, to undo the operation you need to collect all the insert ids from insert queries and store them in a session. After hitting the undo button simply delete the records based on the stored ids

Answer (score -1):

1. First, start a transaction by using the **START TRANSACTION**  statement.
2. Perform whatever you want.
3. Finally, commit the transaction using the **COMMIT** statement to save data.
4. If you don't want to change roll back the current transaction and cancel its changes, you use the **ROLLBACK** statement.

Refer below link for more information.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($connection, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);

try {
    mysqli_query($connection, $yourSelectQuery1);
    mysqli_query($connection, $yourSelectQuery2);
    mysqli_query($connection, $yourSelectQuery3);

    mysqli_commit($connection);
} catch($e) {
    mysqli_rollback($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: I think some misunderstanding is there between us. I need Rollback all SQL queries after successfully executed and reflected data in tables. In case If some one made transaction by mistake.   @AakashTushar

Comment: Your question is misleading